# Xcode 4.5 callStackSymbol not Symbolicated

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, crash-reports, callstack, debug-symbols

I am using `NSException`'s `callStackSymbol` to log the stack trace of my crash and send it to my server.

I am getting this kind of stack trace from my release ipa file and/or the original released app on iTunes.

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x35d048a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x33928259 objc_exception_throw + 32
2   CoreFoundation                      0x35c591d7 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 186
3   MyApp                               0x00125443 _mh_execute_header + 300099
4   Foundation                          0x3512a933 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 414
5   CoreFoundation                      0x35cd8a33 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
6   CoreFoundation                      0x35cd8699 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 364
7   CoreFoundation                      0x35cd726f __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
8   CoreFoundation                      0x35c5a4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
9   CoreFoundation                      0x35c5a36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
10  GraphicsServices                    0x339f5439 GSEventRunModal + 136
11  UIKit                               0x33432cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
12  MyApp                               0x00124b07 _mh_execute_header + 297735
13  MyApp                               0x000deaf0 _mh_execute_header + 10992
```

And I'm getting this on debug/release via Simulator (I was getting this kind of stack trace before supporting iOS 6.0):

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x35d048a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x33928259 objc_exception_throw + 32
2   CoreFoundation                      0x35c591d7 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 186
3   MyApp                               0x00125443 [MyApp didAppLoad] + 300099
4   Foundation                          0x3512a933 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 414
5   CoreFoundation                      0x35cd8a33 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
6   CoreFoundation                      0x35cd8699 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 364
7   CoreFoundation                      0x35cd726f __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
8   CoreFoundation                      0x35c5a4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
9   CoreFoundation                      0x35c5a36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
10  GraphicsServices                    0x339f5439 GSEventRunModal + 136
11  UIKit                               0x33432cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
12  MyApp                               0x00124b07 [MyApp appLoad] + 297735
13  MyApp                               0x000deaf0 [MyApp start] + 10992
```

My question is, what should I do to make it symbolicated (do not offer me of using symbolicating tools because it was working on the previous releases and supporting iOS 6 using Xcode 4.5, it became like this, and it is not iTunes.crash file).

If there's any chance of getting the reason of the crash from iTunes.crash, can you teach me how to do it? I searched for about 6 hours and I still didn't find any clue.

Thanks in advance!